# Noise level detector circuit design (AC to DC to PWM)

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, circuit-design, pwm, rectifier

So I'm building a sound level detector. Design requirements are:

- Only basic circuit elements
- No IC's, except for op-amps
- Sound level will be displayed with a blinking LED
- Blinking LED will be controlled with Pulse Width Modulation (PWM)
- Sound level, and therefore the PWM, will have several distinct levels, let's say, 0%, 50% and 90%

Here is my general design schema:
[image: general design schema]

AC from microphone will be converted to DC through a full-wave rectifier. The obtained input DC will be passed through 3 parallel op-amp comparators (one for each sound level).

Now, as a sound loudness display, I need to use a blinking LED, whose on/off times will be determined by a PWM input — a 25% duty cycle will mean the LED will be on for 25% of the period and 75% off.

In order to obtain a PWM, we need triangular waves, so, to each comparator, a triangular wave generator will be connected, with amplitudes 0%, 50%, and 90% of the max voltage, respectively.

Now, I am uncertain about a couple of things, mainly:

- Would a full-wave rectified output work with triangular wave method?
  If yes, then I suppose the period of output PWM will be twice as
  less? If no, then what other method would I use to convert AC from
  the mic to DC?
- In the end, now that I have outputs from all comparators, can I just
  "combine" them (through comparators again I suppose?) like this?
  [image]

**Equipment:**

- Passive elements (resistors, capacitors, inductors, diodes)
- LEDs
- Analog Microphone
- Op-Amps
- DC Power Supply in the laboratory

Any general commentary/advice on the circuit design would be highly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Are you using compressed sound? then the peaks may  be pretty constant unless you use different band filters. Maybe you want log levels.

Comment: _"Blinking LED will be controlled with Pulse Width Modulation (PWM)"_ how fast do you want the LED to blink?

Comment: "Only basic circuit elements" please **list comprehensively** (no "and so on..." or "etc") what these are to you. I've seen way too many questions where suddenly a specific component wasn't on the secret list of allowed devices, after I've (we've) put a lot of thought into an answer.

Comment: @BruceAbbott the LED will blink only once per second, it will be the **duration** of the blink that's changing, that's why I'm using PWM. The period will be 1 second, so, with PWM of duty cycle 25%, then the LED will light up for 0.25 secs and be off for 0.75 secs.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thank you for your comment, I added the equipment list to the question.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 sorry but I honestly don't know what a lot of that means :D I'm just using a simple electret analog mic element on the circuit, with a driver preamp shown here: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu765/tidu765.pdf

Comment: look up "color organ schematic"